# How to change the on-click Event of a Button in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

I have the Problem that is have a table with an edit Button in the last `<td>` of each row. When edit is pressed the `<td>`s change to `<input>`s, which works perfectly fine. My Button looks like this:

```dart
<td><button on-click="{{editThis}}">Edit</button></td>
```

So when its pressed, the `editThis` function will be called. But i want that my Button now will display "Save" and if pressed should call the "saveThis" function.

```dart
void editThis(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
   e.preventDefault();
   /* ... does not matter ... */

   (sender as ButtonElement).text = "Save"; 
   (sender as ButtonElement).setAttribute("on-click", {{saveThis}});
}
```

The Button still does call the `editThis` function. Dartium displays this:

```dart
<button on-click="{{saveThis}}">Save</button>
```

Any ideas why it does not work or another way how to  solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a Solution myself :)

```dart
    void editThis(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
    e.preventDefault();
    print("edit called");

    /* Does not matter */

    ButtonElement newButton = new ButtonElement();
    newButton.text = "Save";
    newButton.onClick.listen((event) => saveThis());
    sender.replaceWith(newButton);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle both clicks in a single click function:

```dart
void editThis(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
   e.preventDefault();
   /* ... does not matter ... */

   var button = (sender as ButtonElement);
   if(button.text == "Save") {
     // Do save action
     button.text = "Edit";
   } else if (button.text == "Edit") {
     // Do edit action
     button.text = "Save";
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, this would work i guess. But i dont like that the function handles the called function of the Button by the text on the Button. That should bei the Job of the on-click attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to have a status in your elements model like `@observable bool isEdit = false;` and then use

```dart
<td>
  <template if="{{isEdit}}">
    <button on-click="{{editThis}}">Edit</button>
  </template>
  <template if="{{!isEdit}}">
    <input type="text"><button on-click="{{saveThis}}">Save</button>
  </template>
</td>
```

Comment: td and template tag dont work together unfortunaly. Its a known Problem. The td will bei ignored by the Browser. That was my actual problem, so i created an extended td tag in Polymer, so i can change my td tag without the use of template tags within a table

Comment: I modified my answer a bit. Your question doesn't contain enough information to see how/where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Since i have an edit button for each tr, all Buttons would change. I also think that the template tag doesnt even work inside table

Comment: There is a known Problem within Polymer. I ll answer this later when im home.

Comment: It would work inside a `<td>`. On `<tr>` I don't know for sure. `<tr template if="{{xxx}">` could work. If you have a model for each of these cells it would work but your question does not contain enough information to see how you want use it.

Comment: I know but there is a workaround. https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-compat.html but it only mentions `template repeat=...` but not `template if=...` and I have never tried it.
Also https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html

Comment: The original Problem: I have a table and each row does have an edit Button. If that button is pressed all the td tag should have a text input tag containing the values. So two templates for each td would bei Too much. <tr template ... > wont work since the td tags will bei ignored by the Browser, because the tds wont See the table around the template. Tried pretty much everything with template and it didnt work. So i extended the td with Polymer and it did work. Except changing the on-click of the Button

Comment: This description is still to generic to be able to give some advice. I need to see some HTML how your `<tr>`s and `<td>`s should look like when in normal mode and when in edit mode and how the rows are built (how the model can be accessed) (If you do provide some more code, please edit the question - code in comments is unreadable).

Comment: Since this is a question about changing the onclick event on the button and not about tds and templates, I'll make a new Question on that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263218/insert-input-tag-into-td-tags-via-templates