# Insert Input Tag into td tags via templates

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a table and each row does have an edit Button. If that button is pressed all the td tag should have a text input tag containing the values. So two templates for each td would bei Too much. `<tr template ... >` wont work since the td tags will bei ignored by the Browser, because the tds wont See the table around the template. Tried pretty much everything with template and it didnt work.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> td11 </td>
      <td> td12 </td>
      <td> <button on-click="{{someFunc}}"/> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> td21 </td>
      <td> td22 </td>
      <td> <button on-click="{{someFunc}}"/> </td>  <!-- this Button will be pressed -->
   </tr>
</table>
```

After the Button is pressed the table should look like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> td11 </td>
      <td> td12 </td>
      <td> <button on-click="{{someFunc}}"/> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> <input type="text" value="td21" /> </td>
      <td> <input type="text" value="td22" /> </td>
      <td> <button on-click="{{someFunc}}"/> </td>  <!-- this Button will be pressed -->
   </tr>
</table>
```

Since is have pretty big tables, templates in each td is not an option. I currently have a workaround at the moment where is use extended td tags with polymer.

Comment: You could read the value of the td and insert an element (input) via js... Is this a js question?

Comment: No it s Not a js question.  I wrote 'via templates' ;)

Comment: How do you create the rows (`<tr>`) are they static HTML or generated by code?
I guess the table is inside the template of a custom Polymer element?

Comment: They are generated by code, and yes its inside a polymer element.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <template if="{{info['row1']['active'] == false}}">td11</template>
        <template if="{{info['row1']['active'] == true}}"><input type="text" value="td11"></template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <template if="{{info['row1']['active'] == false}}">td12</template>
        <template if="{{info['row1']['active'] == true}}"><input type="text" value="td12"></template>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id="row1" on-click="{{someFunc}}">Click Me</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

With the backing code containing something like this

```
Map info = toObservable({'row1': {'active': false}});

someFunc(Event e) {
    if(info[e.target.id]['active'] == false) {
      info[e.target.id]['active'] = true;
    } else {
      info[e.target.id]['active'] = false;
    }
}
```

You can do it using other types of backing data structures, and have something simpler than the info map I created, but I think this is the type of thing you're after.